# Higher z-Index on an unknown website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I am trying to make a nice UI for a userscript i did to enhance the Moodle at my school.

I need to make a progressbar at the top of the browser viewport, so wherever the user scrolls, it will always be visible.

I know it has to have `position:fixed;` but i can't deal with z-Indexes. I tried everything that came to my mind, from maximum z-Indexes, to appending on body, on document, ..., but no luck.

This is the code i have now (a bit messy. i am adding html using jquery so...):

```
$("#page-header").append($("<div id='progress_container' style='background-color:black;position:fixed;'><div id='progress' style='height:15px;background-color:green;width:0%;'></div></div>"));
```

A little bit more beautiful, (im appending this to `$("#page-header")`):

```
<div id='progress_container' style='background-color:black; position:fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;'>
    <div id='progress' style='height:15px; background-color:green; width:0%;'></div>
</div>
```

Still messy.

I just need it to be on top of everything.

The question is, is there any way to override z-Indexes, or to know the highest one on a page to put mine even higher, is what i am trying to do possible?

Comment: It is messy because of those inline styles. :)

Comment: @bažmegakapa I know, but it's easier for me to build them like this than making objects for each and adding one CSS rule per line of code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with z-indexes?

Comment: @gcq It would certainly be much more readable though (well, the best would be using separate CSS of course). What is easier now, becomes a pain in the ass later. Maybe you have to type more, but you will make less mistakes and you will be able to understand your "mess" even one week later :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa keep in mind it is a userscript. I could add style tags, but meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not visible because it has zero width.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. When the progressbar wasn't fixed, it worked perfect without specifying a width. I guess being fixed changes things a little bit.

Comment: @gcq A simple block element will always try to take up the available space in its parent. But when you position it (absolute or fixed), it will instead try to take up the width of its children. So when it is empty, and has no dimension other than zero given, it will actually be invisible. In a nutshell. No need to feel stupid btw, we all got through these stages :).